# The contract code couldn't be stored, please check your gas amount while deploying contract

Tags: web3js, truffle, truffle-contract

I'm trying to deploy 3 contract in 2_deploy_contract (I deploy all 3) but after the first is deployed I get the following error : The contract code couldn't be stored, please check your gas amount.

Comment: Please post your contract and deployment code.

Answer (score 0):

This is a general error might not be a gas amount issue.
For me it happened when inheriting an interface and not implementing all functions in the interface.